# Is there any way to prevent automatic sorting npm-packages in package.json after "npm install"?

Tags: npm

My team wants to sort pacakge.json by ourselves.

However, after "npm install some-package", a list of npm-packages is automatically sorted in package.json.

Is there any npm-package or any way to prevent this automatic sorting in package-json?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `package.json` is not modified via npm unless you add option `--save`. To make sure that `package.json` is always sorted the way you want it, you should add a script to **normalize** the file (read it, sort keys, write back) and call this script before each commit to clean up whatever state the file was changed to. Normalization can be done for instance with npm package [write-pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-pkg) or with its underlying package [write-json-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/write-json-file) and a custom sorting function. One method to make sure the script gets called is a pre-commit hook with [lint-staged](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged).